# What is the pythonic way of adding a lot of setup code to an __init__ method?

Tags: python

I am making an autograder that takes in an +100 excel sheets and automatically marks them. A pretty basic automation task.

I'm doing this by building a class called `Marking`, a simplified version is shown below:

```
class Marking():
    # Get the list of all excel files
    def __init__(self, directory_data):
        self.files_data = os.listdir(directory_data)
        self.questions = []

    # Get a single workbook 
    def load_workbook(self, order):
         self.workbook = load_workbook(self.files_data[order])

    # Set the questions and their answers
    def set_question(self, question):
         self.questions.append(question)

m = Marking('../data/')

# Input question #1 as a dictionary
m.set_question({
...
    })

# Input question #2 as a dictionary
m.set_question({
...
    })
```

My issue is that I have 29 questions, and I feel like the way I'm initializing the questions is unwieldy and unpythonic. The other option that I have is just putting those 29 questions directly into the **init** method, but that seems even worse to me.

I've tried looking online for how to do what I'm doing in a better and more scalable way, but I couldn't find an answer.

Edited:

Here is examples of how the questions look like:

```
m.set_question({
    'type': 'range',
    'range0': 0.05,
    'range1': 0.2,
    'location': 'J241',
    'unit_location': 'K241',
    'marks_available': 1
    })

m.set_question({
    'type': 'simple',
    'answer': 6,
    'location': 'J254',
    'marks_available': 1
    })

m.set_question({
    'type': 'error',
    'theo': 'E254',
    'meas': 'J190',
    'location': 'J254',
    'marks_available': 1
    })
```

Comment: Maybe store the questions in a config file in JSON, YAML, etc.?

Comment: Consider what `seq_question` actually does: it's just a wrapper around some list's `append` method. You could just as easily pass a list of questions directly to `__init__`, and add them to `self.questions` directly, or with a loop, or with `extend`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that it's going to be very ugly to do this 29 times, or to call your constructor with 29 dictionaries as arguments, I would suggest you serialize these dictionaries in a file, and then have your `__init__` read them in. You could pass the name of the file to the constructor to allow for flexibility.

Comment: That sounds like the more scalable option for the next batch of labs I have to mark. I'll use a separate YAML/JSON file as the questions.

Answer (score 0):

To convert a list of dictionaries to a YAML file, this is how to do it:

(% pip install pyyaml)

```
# List of Dictionaries
# questions = [{...}, {...}]

import yaml
print(yaml.dump(questions))
```